# How to remove "Site Home" tab in Moodle Mobile app?

Tags: moodle, moodle-mobile

In Moodle Academy course in creating [Make your plugin mobile app compatible](https://moodle.academy/enrol/index.php?id=71) Greetings tab is added to the mobile app using [CoreMainMenuHomeDelegate](https://moodledev.io/general/app/development/plugins-development-guide#options-only-for-coremainmenuhomedelegate).

Is there a way to use CoreMainMenuHomeDelegate to remove Site-Home tab? How can I remove the Site-Home tab from the Moodle Mobile App?

I have read Moodle docs but I am unable to find a way to use this delegate to remove tabs from mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Go to sitehome.ts located at moodleapp/src/core/features/sitehome/services/sitehome.ts

Find
`if (hasContent || hasCourseBlocks) { return true; }`
make return to false